# Sum always returns to 1 in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i am joinig two table `task` and `taskdetail`

```
select t.task_id,td.task_id,td.task_detail_id,td.status 
from task t , task_detail td 
where td.task_id=t.task_id and td.status='ACTIVE'
```

It is returning 5 records . But for `task` id 5 there  is two `taskdetail` which are actives so i want to have another column as `totalactive` which should have value sum of all `ACTIVE` against task. For this i have added:

``` SUM(CASE WHEN sd.status='ACTIVE' THEN 1 else 0 END) as totalactive and ``GROUP BY td.task_detail_id ```

but it returns 1 in all cases.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsG0c.png)

```
+---+---------+---------+----------------+----------+-------------+
|No | task_id | task_id | task_detail_id |  status  | totalactive |
+---+---------+---------+----------------+----------+-------------+
| 1 |    2    |    2    |       3        |  ACTIVE  |      1      |
| 2 |    3    |    3    |       5        |  ACTIVE  |      1      |
| 3 |    4    |    4    |       6        |  ACTIVE  |      1      |
| 4 |    5    |    5    |       8        |  ACTIVE  |      1      |
| 5 |    5    |    5    |       9        |  ACTIVE  |      1      |
+---+---------+---------+----------------+----------+-------------+
```

as there are `8,9` two `task detail` against single task `5` i want to have count 2 in both last row

Comment: Please use 21st century `JOIN` syntax. It's been 20 years now since SQL:1999.

Comment: @TheImpaler, and 27 years since SQL-92...

Comment: @jarlh You're right. For some reason I thought it was introduced in SQL:1999 but, as you say, it was SQL-92.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have to substitute as a sub query `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_detail tdd where tdd.task_id=t.task_id and tdd.status='ACTIVE') as totalActive`

```
  select t.task_id,td.task_id,td.task_detail_id,td.status ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_detail tdd where tdd.task_id=t.task_id and tdd.status='ACTIVE') as totalActive
  from task t , task_detail td 
  where td.task_id=t.task_id and td.status='ACTIVE'
```

It will return total count of taskdetail against task.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by `td.task_id` or `t.task_id`

```
select t.task_id, td.task_id, td.task_detail_id, count(1) as totalactive
  from task t 
  join task_detail td on td.task_id=t.task_id 
 where td.status='ACTIVE'
 group by td.task_id
```

or

```
select t.task_id, td.task_id, td.task_detail_id,
       sum(case when td.status='ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as totalactive
  from task t 
  join task_detail td on td.task_id=t.task_id      
 group by td.task_id
```

not to count seperately for each `task_detail_id`

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/XUOGL41483)</kbd>

Comment: using this there is only record for taskId 5

Comment: Using above count is okay but records missing for multiple taskdetail

Comment: @VivekSahni OK, I added the remaining columns also, but only one value of `task_detail_id` will be listed for the records with the values 8 and 9, since they're grouped.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with query:

```
select t.task_id,td.task_id,td.task_detail_id,td.status, count(status) as numberActive  
from task t , task_detail td 
where td.task_id=t.task_id and td.status='ACTIVE'
group by td.task_id
```

Comment: what is `active` in count ?

Comment: sorry, i missed. It's count(status) or count(1)